# The rules of my Guessing Game are not being followed

Tags: python

```
import random

a = random.randint(1,100)
b = input("Input a number to guess: ")
c = int(b)
guesses = []

while c != a :
    guesses.append(c)
    c = int(input("Input a number to guess: "))
    if c < 1 or c > 100:
        print("OUT OF BOUNDS")
        continue
    if c == a:
        print("That's right!!")
        break
    if len(guesses) >= 2:
        if abs(a - c) > abs(a - guesses[-2]):
            print("Colder")
        else:
            print("Warmer")
    if len(guesses) == 1:
        if abs(a - c) <= 10:
            print("Warm!")
        else:
            print("Cold")

print(guesses)
```

The game rules are:

1. If a player's guess is less than 1 or greater than 100, say "OUT OF BOUNDS"
2. On a player's first turn, if their guess is within 10 of the number, return "WARM!" further than 10 away from the number, return "COLD!"
3. On all subsequent turns, if a guess is closer to the number than the previous guess return "WARMER!" farther from the number than the previous guess, return "COLDER!"
4. When the player's guess equals the number, tell them they've guessed correctly and how many guesses it took!

But the above code isn't working, it's not showing warmer and colder correctly, also it shows warm and cold after 2nd input. How to fix this?

Comment: `guesses[-2]` is two guesses ago, not the previous guess.

Comment: The `c` variable is unnecessary. You can instead write `b = int(input("Input a number to guess: "))`. Just a tip.

Comment: in your current code if the person guesses correctly on the first try then the while loop will never run and it will never print that they were correct

Comment: You have a first guess before your loop that you add to your list of guesses but do not check properly. You would be better off getting rid of it and adding the number you just read in the loop to your list.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO :) (I assume you're new since I wrote the same thing in my first weeks of college too)

Multiple things:

Use `elif` whenever you have distinct cases.

As @Aaron mentioned, if you have a correct guess from the beginning, you don't even enter the while-loop and don't `print("That's right!!")`. Easiest fix would be to put that after the while-loop, since you know that the loop will only be exited once the answer was correct.
Different (more elegant) approach would be to make a `while true` loop and wait for the `break`

As @Justin mentioned, `c` is unnecessary, you can just write all user Input into `b`

Edit: (Since I dont have enough SO reputation I'll say it here: `guesses[-2]` is correct python indexing to get the second last element. `guesses[-1]` would be the last element which would be `c`.

Comment: "continue only exits the if-statement, not the entire while-loop iteration" No, `continue` skips the rest of the iteration and continues the loop.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I will edit that out

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine what happens to your first guess:

```
b = input("Input a number to guess: ")
c = int(b)
# c is your first guess
guesses = []

# If the first guess is correct you skip the loop entirely, so you don't print "That's right"
while c != a :
    # You add c to your list of guesses
    guesses.append(c)
    # Now you abandon your first guess and read a new guess
    c = int(input("Input a number to guess: "))
```

Your first guess gets added to your list of guesses but not really checked properly. Each iteration, you add the previous guess to your list, and then process a new guess.

Rather than that, you could get rid of the guess before your loop, and add the guess inside your loop to your list of guesses as soon as you read it. (That way your use of `guesses[-2]` would be correct as the guess from the previous turn in the loop.)

Something like this:

```
import random

a = random.randint(1,100)
guesses = []

while True:
    c = int(input("Input a number to guess: "))
    guesses.append(c)
    if c < 1 or c > 100:
        print("OUT OF BOUNDS")
        continue
    if c == a:
        print("That's right!!")
        break
    if len(guesses) >= 2:
        if abs(a - c) > abs(a - guesses[-2]):
            print("Colder")
        else:
            print("Warmer")
    if len(guesses) == 1:
        if abs(a - c) <= 10:
            print("Warm!")
        else:
            print("Cold")

print(guesses)
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded your code. that the unvalid guesses(input that are bigger than 100 and smaller than 1) not will be part of the guesses.
I also fixed the first guess.

```
import random

a = random.randint(1, 100)
c = 0
guesses = []
while True:
    c = int(input("Input a number to guess: "))
    if c < 1 or c > 100:
        print("OUT OF BOUNDS")
    else:
        guesses.append(c)
        if c == a:
            print("That's right!!")
            break
        elif len(guesses) >= 2:
            if abs(a - c) > abs(a - guesses[-2]):
                print("Colder")
            else:
                print("Warmer")
        elif len(guesses) == 1:
            if abs(a - c) <= 10:
                print("Warm!")
            else:
                print("Cold")
print("You have done a total of "+str(len(guesses))+" guesses")
print(guesses)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were actually quite close. Getting the user input bouth outside the loop and inside the loop is what tripped you up since the outer guess was stored, but never vetted by your logic.  The code below cleans things up, but the logic is pretty much the same as yours.

Example:

```
import random
pick = random.randint(1,100)

guess_list = []

while True:
    guess = int(input("Guess a picked number between 1 and 100: "))
    guess_list.append(guess)
    
    if guess < 1 or guess > 100:
        print("OUT OF BOUNDS")
        continue
    if guess == pick:
        print("That's right!!")
        break

    if len(guess_list) > 1:
        if abs(pick - guess) > abs(pick - guess_list[-2]):
            print("Colder")
        else:
            print("Warmer")
    else:
        if abs(pick - guess) <= 10:
            print("Warm!")
        else:
            print("Cold")

print(f"Guessed it in this many tries: {len(guess_list)}")
```

Output:

```
Guess a picked number between 1 and 100:  50
Cold
Guess a picked number between 1 and 100:  75
Warmer
Guess a picked number between 1 and 100:  87
Colder
Guess a picked number between 1 and 100:  63
Warmer
Guess a picked number between 1 and 100:  57
Colder
Guess a picked number between 1 and 100:  69
Warmer
Guess a picked number between 1 and 100:  72
Colder
Guess a picked number between 1 and 100:  66
Warmer
Guess a picked number between 1 and 100:  65
That's right!!
Guessed it in this many tries: 9
```